# pandas: turn column's values and existing columns into multi-columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I'm trying to take an existing column with duplicated values, and turn it into a header of itself. Then I want to use part of the original header, so that in the end I'll have a multi-columns header.

I'm basically trying to turn this:

```
            ticker      PX_LAST PX_OPEN 
date
20000103    company1    1234    6543
20000104    company1    2345    7654
20000105    company1    3465    8765
20000106    company1    4567    9876
20000103    company2    1       6
20000104    company2    2       7
20000105    company2    3       8
20000106    company2    4       9
```

into this:

```
ticker      company1                company2
field       PX_LAST     PX_OPEN     PX_LAST     PX_OPEN
date
20000103    1234        6543        1           6
20000104    2345        7654        2           7
20000105    3465        8765        3           8
20000106    4567        9876        4           9
```

I've been playing with `DataFrame.pivot` and `DataFrame.pivot_table` but I can't figure it out.

I've also tried to iterate over `DataFrame.iterrows()` but I think it's way too slow and its readability is pretty bad compared to the aforementioned methods in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> (df.reset_index()
      .set_index(['date','ticker'])
      .unstack().swaplevel(axis='columns')
      )

ticker   company1 company2 company1 company2
          PX_LAST  PX_LAST  PX_OPEN  PX_OPEN
date                                        
20000103     1234        1     6543        6
20000104     2345        2     7654        7
20000105     3465        3     8765        8
20000106     4567        4     9876        9
```

EDIT:

```
>>> (df.reset_index()
      .set_index(['date','ticker'])
      .unstack().swaplevel(axis='columns')
      .sort_index(axis=1)
     )

ticker   company1         company2        
          PX_LAST PX_OPEN  PX_LAST PX_OPEN
date                                      
20000103     1234    6543        1       6
20000104     2345    7654        2       7
20000105     3465    8765        3       8
20000106     4567    9876        4       9
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working but I changed the question a little (removed duplications from `ticker` row.).